# create copy of elements along with their values using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert xml code using xslt. 
Below is the strcture of my XML:

```
    <Response>
    <Case>
    <CaseID>...</CaseID>
    ...
    <BillStatusCode typecode="1">type description</BillStatusCode>
    </Case>
    </Response>
```

I want to convert it into something like this:

```
   ...
   <BillStatusCode>
   <BillStatusCode>type description</BillStatusCode>
   <typecode>1</typecode>
   </BillStatusCode>
```

XSLT code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

It gave me this output:

```
    <Response>
    <BillStatusCode>
    <typecode>1</typecode>type description</BillStatusCode>
    </Response>
```

Would appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your XSLT here with explaining the logic behind the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not completely clear to me what you want to achieve.

maybe the following code points to the direction you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BillStatusCode">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot leu. This is exactly what I wanted. I want to create a generic code so I changed it a little. Thanks for the help.